# Get the pixel screen size in Spark AR studio (for Facebook)

Tags: javascript, facebook, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I am starting to work with [Spark AR studio](https://www.sparkar.com/ar-studio/) and I looking for to get the screen size in pixel to compare the coordinate obtained by the `gesture.location` on Tap.

```
TouchGestures.onTap().subscribe((gesture) => {
  // ! The location is always specified in the screen coordinates
  Diagnostics.log(`Screen touch in pixel = { x:${gesture.location.x}, y: ${gesture.location.y} }`);

  // ????
});
```

The `gesture.location` is in pixel (screen coordinate) and would like to compare it with the screen size to determine which side of the screen is touched.

Maybe using the [Camera.focalPlane](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ar-studio/reference/classes/scenemodule.camera) could be a good idea...

**Update**

I tried two new things to have the screen size:

```
const CameraInfo = require('CameraInfo');
Diagnostics.log(CameraInfo.previewSize.height.pinLastValue());

const focalPlane = Scene.root.find('Camera').focalPlane;
Diagnostics.log(focalPlane.height.pinLastValue());
```

But both return `0`

Comment: The `CameraInfo.previewSize` should work, but since it is a signal to debug it you should use something like this `Diagnostics.watch("Width: ", CameraInfo.previewSize.width);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally,

Using the Device Info in the Patch Editor and passing these to the script works!

First, add a variable "to script" in the editor:

[image]

Then, create that in patch editor:

[image]

And you can grab that with this script:

```
const Patches = require('Patches');
const screenSize = Patches.getPoint2DValue('screenSize');
```

My mistake was to use `Diagnostic.log()` to check if my variable worked well.

Instead use `Diagnostic.watch()`:

```
Diagnostic.watch('screenSize.x', screenSize.x);
Diagnostic.watch('screenSize.y', screenSize.y);
```

Comment: with latest version the api syntax is: const screenSize = await Patches.outputs.getPoint2D('screenSize');

Answer (score 3):

This answer might be a bit late but it might be a nice addition for people looking for a solution where the values can easily be used in script, I came across this code(not mine, forgot to save a link):

```
var screen_height = 0;
Scene.root.find('screenCanvas').bounds.height.monitor({fireOnInitialValue: true}).subscribe(function (height) {
    screen_height = height.newValue;
});
var screen_width = 0;
Scene.root.find('screenCanvas').bounds.width.monitor({fireOnInitialValue: true}).subscribe(function (width) {
    screen_width = width.newValue;
});
```

This worked well for me since I couldn't figure out how to use Diagnostics.log with the data instead of Diagnostics.watch.

Comment: What is this screenCanvas?

Answer (score 1):

Screen size is available via the Device Info patch output, after dragging it to patch editor from the Scene section.
[image: Device Info patch]

Comment: I need to have these values in the script. And I don't succeed to add these to the script. See my last update

Answer (score 0):

Now in the open beta (as of this post) you can drag Device from the scene sidebar into the patch editor to get a patch that outputs screen size, screen scale, and safe area inserts as well as the self Object.
[The Device patch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYSs4.png)

Answer (score 0):

The device size can be used in scripts using `CameraInfo.previewSize.width` and `CameraInfo.previewSize.height` respectively. For instance, if you wanted to get 2d points representing the min/max points on the screen, this'd do the trick.

```js
const CameraInfo = require('CameraInfo')
const Reactive = require('Reactive')

const min = Reactive.point2d(
  Reactive.val(0),
  Reactive.val(0)
)
const max = Reactive.point2d(
  CameraInfo.previewSize.width,
  CameraInfo.previewSize.height
)
```

(The point I want to emphasize being that `CameraInfo.previewSize.width` and `CameraInfo.previewSize.height` are `ScalarSignal`s, not number literals.)

> **Edit:** Here's a link to the documentation: https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/reference/classes/camerainfomodule